# Identify this movie about zombies whose head is cut off by an iron gear

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I watched this movie more than 15 years ago. My guess it was around 2000's or older. This movie is in color and in english language. I only remember some scene form this movie.

This is what I remember:
The protagonist is cornered by zombies. I think it was only 2 zombies. Then the protagonist grab an iron gear and throw it to the zombie. The zombie neck is cut off and protagonist flee. Some time after this scene, the second zombie fix his neck with a duct tape. But, it not really works because when the first zombie is eating, the food is come out through the duct tape.

Another thing I can remember:

- The protagonist has a brown dog
- One zombie is big  (the headless one) and the other is small. They're around teen age.
- I think he is a bad boy or some kind
- He's white and short haired
- there is a festival some time in the movie
- there is a female exorcist with brown/dark skin with  frizzy hair

**note:**
I'll add more if anything come up to my mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am 99% sure [Idle Hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_Hands) (1999) is the movie you are looking for.

The protagonist's hand is possessed by the devil and that leads him to kill his family and friends.

His friends come back as zombies and he cut off the head of one of them who then uses duct tape to glue it back.

Check the movie poster with the said zombie:

[image]

Comment: yeah. this is it. I remember the zombie guy. thank you